# Does Jetpack compose release onClickListener for LazyColumnFor/LAazyRowFor?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

The current version of jetpack compose is alpha-09, but couldn't find the onClickListener for LazyColumnFor(RecyclerView/Listview).If anyone have any update, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `LazyColumnFor` is deprecated. Use `LazyColumn` instead.

Comment: @Noah i'm using alpha-06 version.so i used LazyColumnFor

Comment: I reccomend using the latest version. Currently 1.0.0-alpha09

Comment: @Noah , actually im waiting for the stable version of compose. There are plentiful changes occurs when upgrading the versions, it really time consuming as well. Heard compose will release stable version in 2021.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the content clickable.
For ex:

```
LazyColumnFor(items) { item ->
    Box(Modifier.clickable(onClick = { //handle onClick })) {
        // Your item layout
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, the click is working for the first click, for the second and following item its not working, when i scroll the list then click it works, but not continuously.

Comment: Thanks @Nagy for your valuable input. I've given box clickable property to the lazycolumn's item view,. And its working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Composable
 fun JobItem(job: Job?=null) {
   Text(text = "companyName $(job?.companyName)")
 }


@Composable
fun JobList(jobList: Flow<PagingData<Job>>) {

val lazyJobItems = jobList.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
val context = LocalContext.current
LazyColumn {
    items(lazyJobItems) {
            job -> Surface(modifier = Modifier.clickable {

        Toast.makeText(context,"CompanyName ${job?.companyName }", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }) { JobItem(job = job!!)  }
       }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @AndroidEntryPoint
  class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        LearningTheme {
            Surface() {
                LazyColumnClickable()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Number $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }
        }
    }}}


@Composable
fun LazyColumnClickable(selectedNumber:(Int)->Unit)
{
 
 LazyColumn{
    items(500){

        Surface(modifier = Modifier.clickable { selectedNumber(it+1) }) {
          Text(text = "Number ${it + 1}",modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp))
            Divider(color= Color.Gray, thickness = 2.dp)
            
        }
    }
    }}
```